# How to retrieve objects inside an array, if matches given condition, using mongodb 3.0.0

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to project all the objects from an array, if it matches the given condition.

I have following data

```
{
    _id : 1,
    em : 'abc@12s.net',
    name : 'NewName',
    od : 
    [
        {
            "oid" : ObjectId("1234"),
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-05T13:20:10.718Z")
        },
        {
            "oid" : ObjectId("2345"),
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
        },
        {
            "oid" : ObjectId("57766"),
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-13T13:20:10.718Z")
        }
    ]       
},
{
    _id : 2,
    em : 'ab6c@xyz.net',
    name : 'NewName2',
    od : 
    [
        {
            "oid" : ObjectId("1234"),
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
        },
        {
            "oid" : ObjectId("2345"),
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-12T13:20:10.718Z")
        },
        {
            "oid" : ObjectId("57766"),
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-05T13:20:10.718Z")
        }
    ]       
}
```

I want to get all the objects from od array, if 'od.ca' comes between range say, if greater than 10th may and less than 15th may.

I tried using aggregate method of mongodb and I am new to this method. My query is as given below.

```
db.userDetail.aggregate(
        {
            $match: 
            {
                'od.ca': 
                {
                    '$gte': '10/05/2016',
                    '$lte': '15/05/2016' 
                },
                lo: { '$ne': 'd' }
            }
        },
        {
            $redact:
            {
                $cond: 
                {
                    if: 
                    {
                        $gte: [ "$$od.ca", '10/05/2016' ],
                        $lte : ["$$od.ca" , '15/05/2016']
                    },
                    then: "$$DESCEND",
                    else: "$$PRUNE"
                }
            }
        })
```

When I am trying to use this command, getting error :-

> assert: command failed: {
>       "errmsg" : "exception: Use of undefined variable: od",
>       "code" : 17276,
>       "ok" : 0
>   } : aggregate failed

Since I am using mongodb 3.0.0 I can not use [$fiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter). So I tried using [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/).

Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing? Is the query correct?

> Also referred [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) Since I am not using 3.2 of mongodb (as I have mentioned), can not use the accepted answer of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

query explanation:

1. $match - match documents for criteria - limit documents to process
2. $unwind - econstructs **od** array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.
3. $match - match documents for criteria
4. $group - this is opposite of $unwind in our case - so we are recreating results array

If you are expecting document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "od" : [{
            "oid" : 1234,
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
        }, {
            "oid" : 2345,
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-12T13:20:10.718Z")
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id" : 1,
    "od" : [{
            "oid" : 2345,
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
        }, {
            "oid" : 57766,
            "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-13T13:20:10.718Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

you can use query bellow:

```
db.userDetail.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                "od.ca" : {
                    $lt : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 2)),
                    $gte : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 4))
                }
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$od"
        }, {
            $match : {
                "od.ca" : {
                    $lt : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 2)),
                    $gte : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 4))
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$_id",
                od : {
                    $push : "$od"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: This query is working. Can you explain what exactly this is doing @profesor79?

Comment: If there will be some more fields along with the od array, in the same level, say 'em', 'name'. In this case if I want to get all those fields also. How this can be achieved? @profesor79

Comment: @titi23 i could check in on Monday,  but add document  schema to your question

Answer (score 0):

The following query gave me the desired result. 
If you are using mongodb-2.6.X up to 3.0.X can use this solution.

```js
var object = {st : "10/05/2016", et : "13/05/2016"};
db.userDetail.aggregate(
  [ 
    {
      $match: 
      {
        "od.ca": 
        {
          '$gte': new Date(object.st),
          '$lte': new Date(object.et)
        },
        "lo" : {$ne : 'd'}
      }
 },
    {
        $project:
        {
   em: 1,
   fna : 1,
   lna : 1,
   ca :1,
   od:
   {
    "$setDifference":
    [{
     "$map":
     {
       "input": "$od",
                      "as": "o",
                      "in":
                      {
                        "$cond":[
                          {
                            "$and":
                            [
                              { "$gte": [ "$$o.ca", new Date(object.st) ] },
                              { "$lte": [ "$$o.ca", new Date(object.et) ] },
                              { "$ne": [ "$$o.oid", ObjectID(config.pid.toString()) 
                                       ] }
                            ]
                          },
                          "$$o",false]
                      }
                    }
                },[false]
                ]
            }
        }
   },
   {$sort : {_id : 1}}
  ];
)
```

If you are using 3.2.X, use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) to get the result.